# Most effective way to parse CSV and take action based on content of row

Tags: python, json, csv, splunk

I have a CSV file that Splunk generates, similar in format to the following:

```
Category,URL,Hash,ID,"__mv_Hash","_mkv_ID"
binary,somebadsite.com/file.exe,12345abcdef,123,,,
callback,bad.com,,567,,,
```

What I need to do is iterate through the CSV file, maintaining header order, and take a different action if the result is a binary or callback.  For this example, if the result is a binary I'll return an arbitrary "clean" or "dirty" rating and if it's a callback I'll just print out the details.

Below is the code I'm currently planning to use, but I'm new to Python and would like feedback on the code and if there is a better way to accomplish this.  I'm also not fully clear on the difference between how I'm handling if the result is binary: `for k in (k for k in r.fieldnames if (not k.startswith("""__mv_""") and not k.startswith("""_mkv_""")))` and how I handle if it's not.  Both achieve the same result, so whats the benefit of one over the other?

```
import gzip
import csv
import json

csv_file = 'test_csv.csv.gz'

class GZipCSVReader:
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self.gzfile = gzip.open(filename)
        self.reader = csv.DictReader(self.gzfile)
        self.fieldnames = self.reader.fieldnames

    def next(self):
        return self.reader.next()

    def close(self):
        self.gzfile.close()

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.reader.__iter__()

def get_rating(hash):
    if hash == "12345abcdef":
        rating = "Dirty"
    else:
        rating = "Clean"
    return hash, rating

def print_callback(result):
    print json.dumps(result, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',',':'))

def process_results_content(r):
    for row in r:
        values = {}
        values_misc = {}

        if row["Category"] == "binary":
            # Iterate through key:value pairs and add to dictionary
            for k in (k for k in r.fieldnames if (not k.startswith("""__mv_""") and not k.startswith("""_mkv_"""))):
                v = row[k]
                values[k] = v
            rating = get_rating(row["Hash"])
            if rating[1] == "Dirty":
                print rating
        else:
            for k in r.fieldnames:
                if not k.startswith("""__mv_""") and not k.startswith("""_mkv_"""):
                    v = row[k]
                    values_misc[k] = v
            print_callback(values_misc)
    r.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    r = GZipCSVReader(csv_file)
    process_results_content(r)
```

Finally, would a `for...else` loop be better rather than doing something such as `if row["Category"] == "binary"`?  For example, could I do something such as:

```
def process_results_content(r):
    for row in r:
        values = {}
        values_misc = {}

        for k in (k for k in r.fieldnames if (not row["Category"] == "binary")):
            v = row[k]
            ...
        else:
            v = row[k]
            ...
```

Seems like that would be the same logic where the first clause would capture anything not binary and the second would capture everything else, but does not seem to produce the correct result.

Comment: The else clause in `for...else:` only runs if no `break` is executed within the loop.

Comment: That makes sense why the else clause in `for...else:` would never run so I can't use that in this example since it will be a mixture of both result.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

My take using the `pandas` library.

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

csv_file = 'test_csv.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
df = df[["Category","URL","Hash","ID"]] # Remove the other columns.

get_rating = lambda x: "Dirty" if x == "12345abcdef" else "Clean"
df["Rating"] = df["Hash"].apply(get_rating) # Assign a value to each row based on Hash value.

print df

j = df.to_json() # Self-explanatory. :)
print j
```

**Result:**

```
   Category                       URL         Hash   ID Rating
0    binary  somebadsite.com/file.exe  12345abcdef  123  Dirty
1  callback                   bad.com          NaN  567  Clean
{"Category":{"0":"binary","1":"callback"},"URL":{"0":"somebadsite.com\/file.exe","1":"bad.com"},"Hash":{"0":"12345abcdef","1":null},"ID":{"0":123,"1":567},"Rating":{"0":"Dirty","1":"Clean"}}
```

If this is your intended result, then just substitute the above to your `GZipReader`, since I did not emulate the opening of the `gzip` file.